# How to user key in math operator

Tags: javascript, html

```
function calculate()
{
var num1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
var num2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
var operator = document.getElementById("operation");
var totalNum = document.getElementById("total");
if (operator == "+")
{
    parseDouble(totalNum = num1 + num2);
}
else if(operator == "-")
{
    parseDouble(totalNum = num1 - num2);
}
total.value = totalNum;
}
```

My output is [object HTMLInputElement].
How to distinguish Math operation??

Comment: Try `switch(){case..}`

Comment: Also, I think you want `document.getElementById("operation").value` there

Comment: Try `operator.value` (or that ^)

Comment: You want to call `parseFloat` on the operands, not on the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code does not give an unexpected result because it cannot distinguish Math operation. There where some other bugs in the code.

```
function calculate()
{
  var num1 = parseDouble(document.getElementById("input1").value);
  var num2 = parseDouble(document.getElementById("input2").value);
  var op = document.getElementById("operation").value;
  var total = document.getElementById("total");
  if (op == "+")
  {
    total.value = num1 + num2;
  }
  else if(op == "-")
  {
    total.value = num1 - num2;
  }
}
```

Comment: there's another bug as well, though. Also, some words of explanation would be nice

Comment: `var totalNum` should be `var total`

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalNum = document.getElementById("total");
```

sets `totalNum` to a reference to a field. I believe you want it to be

```
var total = document.getElementById("total");
```

here. Also, you need

```
var operator = document.getElementById("operation").value;
```

Note the `.value` in the end. Without this, `operation` is neither `"+"` or `"-"`, so the `if`'s are not executed. So the field whose reference is somehow in `total` gets the value of `totalNum` (-> `totalNum.toString()`), which is the reference to the result field and becomes `[Object HTMLInputElement]`.